# What are common strategies for updating python programs?

Tags: python, windows-7, py2exe

I have a Windows program that I made with python and py2exe. I'd like to create an updating feature so that the software can be readily updated.

What are common ways of going about this?

Comment: Same as any other system; once you're doing it with py2exe, it becomes a general question and there's very little special about the fact that it's Python any more.

Comment: Find a toolkit for updating or patching .exe (or binary) files -- or write one yourself Python or some other language (probably not all that hard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you package an app with py2exe, the result is usually a single executable (perhaps with some data files). This is simplest to update by just proposing the user to download and install a new version every once in a while (how you check with a server that such new version exists is a different question).

If you want to reduce the download size the user has to do, application commonly resort to breaking themselves up into multiple DLLs and updating only the relevant DLLs. When you have a Python application you don't have DLLs but you have an even easier option - you can just keep most of your app's logic outside the exe in .pyc files, and update just some of these .pyc files.

Now, mind you, .pyc files are easily "decompilable" into Python (a somewhat obfuscated version of your original code), but having an exe made with py2exe isn't much safer, because py2exe is open-source software and packs all the same files inside the exe anyway.

To conclude, my suggestion is don't bother. How large can your application be? With today's fast connections, it's easier to just make the user download a whole new version than to invest a lot of time into building partial-update functionality into your program.

Comment: Thanks, The security of the code isn't a huge deal, I'm likely going to make it open source by version 2.0. Are there any good ways to communicate with the program so that I can command it to do a popup dialog?

Comment: @Anteater7171: if security isn't an issue, then just pack all your Python libs in a directory (py2exe has an option for it IIRC). I don't understand your last question

Answer (score 3):

If you think your code might benefit others, you could put it up on PyPI. Then having different versions is just updating your package, or telling your clients to use `easy_install` to get the latest version. This doesn't push updates, though.

You can try Esky, which is an auto-update framework for managing different versions, including fetching new versions and rolling back partial updates. It can be found on PyPI.

That said, I haven't used Esky. If you wish to roll your own auto-update feature, you might want to look at [Boxed Dice](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/04/11/python-auto-update-mechanism/) to see how they got around to it.